# How to add a custom MACRO when using NDK?

Tags: android-ndk

I need some custom MACROs in my NDK projects
however I have no ideal how to add and I found no answers
Could anyone please help?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 52):

If you would like to add a special definition when compiling your NDK code (jni) add the following into your Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DMYDEFINE
```

This will define the Macro **MYDEFINE** in your c/c++ code. Here an example

```
#ifdef MYDEFINE
// We build the project with this special macro
#else
// We build without setting the macro in the LOCAL_CFLAGS
#endif
```

Comment: Nice that it worked :P So you might accept the answer hehe :P

Comment: Learn from my mistake: don't miss the `D` in `-DMYDEFINE`

Answer (score 1):

If you understand you correctly, you need to look at how the [C Preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) works.

Do you have any experience in writing C/C++-programs? First off, you should be really picky on what parts of your application you write in native code. Also, you need to keep in mind that the native code will behave totally different when it comes to memory allocation and such, so this really isn't the place for guesswork.

Spend some time getting to know C/C++, design your application wisely so that the parts you want to write in native code is clearly defined, and that it doesn't increase the chance of your application crashing. I'm guessing most projects can do without an native application part, so if you're using it, and don't know *exactly* what you're doing, you should really re-asses whether it's the right thing to do or not.

Comment: I'm doing a migration and I'm a newbie for android，thanks for your advising!

Comment: Agreed. I'd like to add that _if_ someone decides to mix Java and native code for an Android application, try to minimize crossing the JNI boundary. That is: minimize JNI calls as they are relatively expensive. Imho, anyone finding themselves in a situation where high-frequency JNI calls can't be avoided should seriously consider going Java-only. If not for performance reasons, then at least to prevent JNI induced headaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about android makefile MACROs like

> $(call my-dir)

It's exactly same as GNU makefile syntax

[Gnu makefile manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Functions)

For instance:

> reverse = $(2) $(1)
>
> foo = $(call reverse,a,b)
>
> $(warning $(foo))

results:

> b a

Answer (score 1):

To define marcro:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DYOUR_MACRO
```

to define macro with value:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DYOUR_MACRO='"string"'
```

or

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DYOUR_MACRO=123
```

personally, I suggest to use += instead of := to avoid `LOCAL_CFLAGS` been overwritten.